# Starting from $2^1$, the next three consecutive powers of 2 have the same number of digits.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To clarify a bit,
I mean that $2^1$, $2^2$, and $2^3$ all have 1 digit, $2^4$, $2^5$, and $2^6$ all have 2 digits, and so on.

To what power of 2 is this statement true?

Comment: There are four numbers with 4 digits $2^{10},2^{11},2^{12}$ and $2^{13}$.

Comment: Since $3<\log_2(10)<4$, runs of consecutive powers of two having the same number of digits will always be either $3$ long of $4$ long. Since $\log_2(10)$ is closer to $3$ than $4$, they are more often $3$ long than $4$ long.